# How to correctly mix and isolate objects in Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex, mixins

I'm trying to create kind of mixin for Vuex, using modules, but actions are being mixed within modules:

This is the subEvents module:

```
import Form from '../../classes/Form'

import * as mutationsMixin from './mixins/mutations.js'
import * as actionsMixin from './mixins/actions.js'
import * as statesMixin from './mixins/states.js'

const state = merge_objects(statesMixin.common, {
    data: {},

    event: null,

    form: new Form({
        name: null,
    }),
})

const actions = merge_objects(actionsMixin, {
    select() {
        dd('subevent select')
    },
})

const mutations = merge_objects(mutationsMixin, {
    mutateSetEvent(state, payload) {
        state.event = payload
    },
})

dd('subEvents')

export default {
    state,
    actions,
    mutations,
}
```

This is the store

```
/**
 * Imports
 */
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

/**
 * Vuex
 */
Vue.use(Vuex)

/**
 * Global state
 */
import * as actions from './actions'
import * as getters from './getters'
import * as mutations from './mutations'

/**
 * Modules
 */
import gate from './modules/gate'
import events from './modules/events'
import subEvents from './modules/subEvents'
import categories from './modules/categories'
import people from './modules/people'
import roles from './modules/roles'
import institutions from './modules/institutions'
import environment from './modules/environment'

/**
 * State
 */
const state = {
    mounted: false,
}

/**
 * Store
 */
let store = new Vuex.Store({
    state,
    actions,
    getters,
    mutations,
    modules: {
        events,
        people,
        categories,
        environment,
        subEvents,
        gate,
        roles,
        institutions,
    },
})

store.dispatch('environment/absorbLaravel')

export default store
```

This is the merge_object helper:

```
window.merge_objects = (target, ...sources) => {
    return Object.assign(target, ...sources)
}
```

So if you look at the store imports, you'll see that subEvents are being loaded after events, and the action select() (originally coming from the mixin) in the subEvents store above is being overloaded, but when I call events/select(), which is not overloaded, I get 'subevent select' message in console (dd() is a helper for that)

This is an image explaining it a little

[image]

Comment: You are in dangerous territory using `Object.assign` on your mixin objects. This method modifies the object in the first argument. I am not 100% sure this is the cause of your problem though. Consider testing with `Object.assign({}, target, ...sources)` and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Is there a better way to merge objects than using assing?

Comment: @Sumurai8, spot on! Could you write an answer for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) does not create a copy, but instead modifies the object you pass it as the first argument. The function will return the first object.

```js
const a = {};
Object.assign(a, { a: 1 });
console.log(a); // { a: 1 }
```

In your case I don't think you need a deep clone of your object. You just want to not modify the mixin directly. If you call `Object.assign` with a newly created object as the first argument, you will do a shallow copy of all the objects that are in the next arguments.

```
Object.assign({}, target, ...sources)
```

```js
const a = {};
Object.assign({}, a, { a: 1 });
console.log(a); // {}
```

If you need a deep clone (e.g. because there are nested objects in your object that you do not want to share between instances, I would recommend using something like [`lodash.merge`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#merge).